# Converting typeid to namespace for static member access (C++)

Tags: c++

I want to access static member functions based on typeid, rather than listing each out individually.

Here is what I have, which works:

```
if(typeid(*ob) == typeid(Seaweed)) {
    Seaweed::getStaticMember();
}
if(typeid(*ob) == typeid(Coral)) {
    Coral::getStaticMember()
}
```

Here is, in effect, what I'm going for:

```
typeid(*ob)::getStaticMember();
```

In other words, I want to replace the 4 lines above with the 1 below. I've tried a few approaches here but no go. Is there a technique which produces this intended effect?

Comment: Do `Seaweed` and `Coral` have a common base class?

Comment: This honestly looks like a job for a virtual function...

Comment: Actually typeid() doesn't return an actual type, so you can't do something like declarations. It just returns type id (function name, haha), and you can compare it with another typeids.

Comment: Even dishonestly this looks like a job for a virtual function.

Comment: Yes well, now that you all mention it, it seems obvious of course. Just return the static member via a virtual function. Roger that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make that static function a virtual one. Since the called function depends on the type of the instance, it's a property of the instance, not the class itself. It should be a member function.

Another solution would be to wrap the call to the static function into a virtual call.

```
struct SeaObject {
    struct static_caller_t {
        virtual void static_call() = 0;
    };

    virtual auto get_static_caller() const -> static_caller_t& = 0;
};

struct Coral : SeaObject {
    struct static_caller_impl : SeaObject::static_caller_t {
        void static_call() override {
            Coral::getStaticMember();
        }
    } static static_caller;

    auto get_static_caller() const override -> static_caller_impl& {
        return static_caller;
    }
};
```

Then use the static caller:

```
ob->get_static_caller().static_call();
```

Answer (score 1):

what you should have is

```
class IStaticMemberExposable
{
public:
    virtual vector<string> getStaticMember() = 0;
};

class Seaweed : public IStaticMemberExposable
{
    virtual vector<string> getStaticMember() override
    {
        //your implementation here
    }
};

class Coral : public IStaticMemberExposable
{
    virtual vector<string> getStaticMember() override
    {
        //your implementation here
    }
};

//To call it...
ob->getStaticMember();
```

Comment: Don't forget the `override` keyword.

Comment: override is not mandetory, but i have to admit it is something nice to have. thanks for reminding. add.

Comment: `virtual` in derivated classes is optional.